# Discord js profanity filter does send double message after 2 words detected in one message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Is there a way to stop this ?
If it checks the database for words for example (ARE,DOING)
If a message has been send like this: (how are you doing) it triggers 2x delete message and 2x my message.

this is how i have it setup:

```
Database12.find(guild, async(err, data) => {
        splittedMsgs.map((content) =>{
             if(message.content.bot) return
            if (data.Words.includes(content.toLowerCase())){
                
                //deletes the bad message
                message.delete()
                // reply a message when a bad word has been detected
                message.reply(replies[random])
                .then(msg => {
                let time = "5s";
          setTimeout(function () {
           // if (message.author.bot) return;
         //deletes the detected message
            msg.delete();
            
          }, ms(time));
            })
                .catch(console.log("error"));
            };
        });
    
    });
```

I did try a lot, but i don't find a way to stop it looping when 2 words are detected at the same time in one message.

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). That way, it will stop looping through the array, if a given element resolves to true:

```js
Database12.find(guild, async (err, data) => {
    if (message.content.bot) return
    if (splittedMsgs.some((content) => data.Words.includes(content.toLowerCase()))) {
        //deletes the bad message
        message.delete()
        // reply a message when a bad word has been detected
        message.reply(replies[random])
            .then(msg => {
                let time = "5s";
                setTimeout(function () {
                    // if (message.author.bot) return;
                    //deletes the detected message
                    msg.delete();

                }, ms(time));
            })
            .catch(console.log("error"));
    }
});
```

Besides, you should always use the correct array method. You used `Array.map`, which is typically used to create a new array whilst changing each element of the given array [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
If you just want to iterate over each element (without changing it), you should use `Array.forEach` instead [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

If you are interested, [here](https://markoskon.com/array-prototype-methods/) is an article with a short explanation and examples regarding some array methods.

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the trick!!, i will check out that article.